# ESP32 stops looping after 2 loops

Tags: esp32, loop

My code: https://pastebin.com/UmdK33U2

I made a menu so I can send commands. First I connect to the wifi and then I send the command to send a request.

Then when it detects the key datos(); goes true, so the loop detects that and it starts sending requests.
After 2 requests it just doesnt continue.

What I can do?

Btw im using a ESP32.

Thank you!

```
boolean datos = false;

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "pass";

//removed the password and ssid for security, it was there before.
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial)
    ;
  Serial.println("===================================================");
  Serial.println("Welcome to the menu, choose what do you want to do:");
  Serial.println("1º Connect to the Wifi | W");
  Serial.println("2º Scan Wifi | S");
  Serial.println("3º Send data to Website | D");
  Serial.println("===================================================");
  Serial.println("Made by Francine and Javi.");
  Serial.println("===================================================");
}

void scanwifi() {
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("===================================================");
  Serial.println("Scan have been finished.");
  Serial.println("===================================================");
  if (n == 0) {
    Serial.println("===================================================");
    Serial.println("No networks have been found.");
    Serial.println("===================================================");
  } else {
    Serial.print(n); // imprimir en el puerto serial el # de redes encontradas
    Serial.println(" networks have been found.");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // SSID: Nombre de la red; RSSI: Potencia de la red en dBm
      Serial.print(i + 1); //iniciamos en la red # 1...
      Serial.print(": ");
      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i)); //Imprime el nombre de la red
      Serial.print(" (");
      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i)); //Imprime la potencia de la señal en dBm
      Serial.print(")");
      byte encryption = WiFi.encryptionType(i); // en la variable encryption, guardamos el tipo de encriptación de la red
      Serial.print(" Encryption Type: ");
      Serial.println(encryption, HEX); // imprimimos el tipo de encriptación: 2: WPA, 5: WEP, etc. 
      delay(10);
    }
  }
}

void conectarsealwifi() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);

    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  delay(1000);
  setup();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char ch = Serial.read();
    if (ch == 'w' || ch == 'W') {
      conectarsealwifi();
    }
    if (ch == 'S' || ch == 's') {
      scanwifi();
    }
    if (ch == 'd' || ch == 'D') {
      datos = true;
      Serial.println(datos);
    }
    if (datos == true) { // si esta habilitado el sending de datos haz
      //randomN = random(200);
      if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
        HTTPClient http;

        http.begin("removedtheurl"); //Specify the URL
        int httpCode = http.GET();                            //Make the request

        if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code

          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.println(httpCode);
          Serial.println(payload);
          Serial.println("===================================================");

        } else {
          Serial.println(
              "Error on HTTP request, reminder maybe its cloudflare shit.");
        }
        http.end(); //Free the resources
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      }
      delay(2000);

    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you fix your indenting you'll soon find your problem.

Comment: @Majenko Hi, thank you for responding. I dont understand your response, im not a foreign speaker, mind explaining better the solution to my problem?

Comment: The basic layout (indenting) of your program is a mess. If you fix that and lay it out properly you will be able to follow the flow of your program better, and the reason for its behaviour will become apparant.

Comment: @Majenko What I checked is that if I type nothing and I send it the loops continues for 1 row then bakc to normal.

Comment: I know. I can see that by just looking at the flow of your program (after fixing the indenting). If you don't know how to indent properly then please use the auto-format facility in the IDE to do it for you.

Comment: Incidentally, I see that Juraj has fixed it for you in your post. Take a look at that version and tell me where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send from Serial Monitor a character followed by a new line character. This two characters are available. Nothing more to enter the `if (Serial.available()) {` block.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I apply it on my code?

Comment: by moving the `if (datos) {` block out of `if (Serial.available()) {` block?

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Have a good day.